# Twilio Bin console: is there a verb to do what Studio set_variables widget does?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Twilio:
I want to store code to store a value to a flow variable in a Bin named "Get Variable".

I know I can get the same effect by using a SubFlow that incorporates the set_variable widget, and I know I can access a bin that returns json from a function call but I'm wondering, specifically, how I can just chuck a json response into a bin and then use it within studio.

What I think I need is a Response verb that does what the Twilio SetVariable widget does. Google searches like "Twilio bin console "set variable" verb response" haven't helped.

If this is doable, then I'd appreciate an example.

Answer (score 1):

TwiML Bins only support limited logic-based templating using Handlebars to modify your TwiML response. I wouldn't recommend using it for more complex logic that involves storing a variables.